# ImageData loses it's interface when using WebWorker

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, web-worker

I'm trying to use a web worker for processing some ImageData but I am running into problems when trying to put back the image data.

First I send some ImageData to my worker:

```
worker.postMessage({
        'pixels':
          _context.getImageData(0,
            i*(_height / _blindNumber),
            _width,
            _height / _blindNumber),
        'key': i,
        'width': _width,
        'height': _height
        });
```

There I preform some image manipulation and post back a new object containing the modified ImageData.

```
//From worker
self.postMessage({
    'key': data.key,
    'pixels': pixels
  });
```

Then I fetch this and put it in an array:

```
worker.onmessage = function(e) {
  var data = e.data;
  _imgSlices[data.key].pixels = data.pixels;
});
```

Later on I try to use my newly modified ImageData

```
 _canvas.getContext('2d').putImageData(_imgSlices[i].pixels, 0, 0);
```

But I receive the following error: ***"TypeError: Value does not implement interface ImageData."***

If I test the data i get back from my Worker it tells me the data is in fact ImageData:

```
console.log(_imgSlices[i].pixels); //Outputs: [object ImageData]
```

What could have gone wrong?

Thanks!